# Why file is not creating in CGI with Apache?

Tags: c++, ajax, apache, file, cgi

I want to write some contents to a file using CGI with Apache .

**my HTML file :**

using Ajax HTTP method to call CGI script . I am not passing any arguments to the CGI . Finally i am printing response text to a div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

var xhttp;

function loadDoc() {

    try{

          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
          };

          xhttp.open("POST","mycgi.cgi",true);
          xhttp.send();


    }catch (exception){

            alert("Request failed: " + exception.message);
        }
}

</script>

</head>


<body>

<h2>sample ajax</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<div id ="message" />

</body>
</html>
```

and **cgi.cpp file**

Here i creating a file with write mode , write some contents to that file and successfully close . Send response text "successfully write " to HTML back .

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>

    #include "cgicc/Cgicc.h"
    #include "cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h"
    #include "cgicc/HTMLClasses.h"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cgicc;

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

    Cgicc cgi;    

       try {

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("Newcgi.txt",ios::out);
        cout<<"Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
        myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        cout<<"Sucessfully write";
        myfile.close();

       }
       catch(exception& e) {

       }

     return 0;

    }
```

But i can not see any file created in `/var/apache2` or in `/var/www/html` . Why this is happening ? Where should be a new file created ? is it in Apache directory ?

Any code problem ? I am writing to a file with write mode also . I think code is working fine . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you check privileges of your CGI file? Often there is a special user `nobody` which owns `/var/www` and which is used by Apache to execute scripts/processes. Where `Newcgi.txt` is supposed to be created, since the given path is relative?

Comment: if i just create   `/home/user/Desktop/newcgi.txt` nothing is creating in Desktop also . i changed  ` chmod 777 newcgi.txt ` . But nothing is creating in /var/www/html

Comment: Did you hit your CGI process over HTTP at all or Apache returns an error? If it works, then you could print error to stdout obtained by `ofstream::open()` and see what is the reason of failure.

Comment: When i print  cout<<"Sucessfully write"; this is working . I got this  message as response text . So processing fine .

Comment: Check status of the stream, try `ofstream::is_open()` or `ofstream::good()`.

Comment: ofstream::is_open() getting 500 internal server error

Comment: Should my cpp will create Newcgi.txt ? or should i create manually ?

Comment: Your cpp file should create it. The safest way is to set absolute path like `/tmp/Newcgi.txt` and check why the file cannot be created (probably privileges).

Comment: ok . But where should this file create ? inside /var/www/html ?

Comment: As said above, try at `tmp/` directory because anyone should have permissions to create files there. Alternatively, try `cgi-bin` working directory of Apache, where your cpp process should reside (see `httpd.conf` for the exact path of this directory, on my machine it is `/var/www/cgi-bin.`) - take care of privileges.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine ..

Comment: Nice. I've added answer with the summary, so you can vote it and accept it, in case someone else needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of previous comments:

- Check privileges of your CGI file. Often there is a special user *nobody* which owns `/var/www` and which is used by Apache to execute scripts/processes.
- Check if C++ CGI process is hit by Apache, does it return a response over HTTP.
- Check what `ofstream::is_open()` returns, where it tries to create file. Good candidates to store created file by CGI process are `/tmp` and `cgi-bin` working directory (which is configured within `httpd.conf`), often it's `/var/www/cgi-bin/`